# Mistake with array raises questions

Tags: powershell

I made a mistake. I used a FULL STOP between array values rather than a COMMA. What is $x? It appears to be $null. What does this expression mean? Why no error message?

```
PS 18:48  C:\src\t
>$x = 1.2.3
PS 18:48  C:\src\t
>$x
PS 18:48  C:\src\t
>$x.GetType()
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ $x.GetType()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

PS 18:48  C:\src\t
>$null -eq $x
True
PS 18:48  C:\src\t
>$x.Count
0
```

Comment: when i type `1.2.3` the 2nd dot brings up the list of methods available. there is NO method named `3`, so PoSh very politely gives me just that - nothing at all. [*grin*] try it with `'123'.3` to see it happen that way, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.2 is implied as an double type.  the second "." tries to invoke a member (either property or method) from the double, since there is no member of an double named "3", $x becomes $null.

Answer (score 3):

To complement [Paul G's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58142481/45375), which explains that the `.3` in `1.2.3` is interpreted as accessing a property named `3` on the `[double]` value that `1.2` is parsed as:

> Why no error message?

By default, PowerShell *ignores* attempts to access non-existent properties on an object and returns `$null`.

If you use `Set-StrictMode -Version 2` or higher, however, a statement-terminating error occurs:

```
PS> Set-StrictMode -Version 2; 1.2.3
The property '3' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
...
```

See the [`Set-StrictMode` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) for more information.

While `Set-StrictMode` is useful for preventing errors such as misspelled variable and property names, it has notable pitfalls:

- `Set-StrictMode` is dynamically rather than lexically scoped, which means that all code invoked from a scope in which it is in effect is also affected - and such code may not have been designed for that and therefore break; providing a *lexically* scoped strict mode to remedy that is the subject of [this RFC](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-RFC/blob/master/1-Draft/RFC0003-Lexical-Strict-Mode.md).
- with `Set-StrictMode -Version 2` or higher, the implicitly added `.Count` property that unifies PowerShell's handling of scalars and collections is then not available - this should be considered a *bug*, and has been reported in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2798).